# Angular - trouble with fetching from array

Tags: arrays, angular

so in my angular project, I've been instructed to make selectedEmployee: EmpInfo type and set the [value] of the select to emp and then use selectedEmployee as the object that I reference to display the data. I'm really new to Angular and not quite sure how to implement that. I thought that I did it right but in the browser, I'm getting an error that says "cannot read property 'EmpKey' of undefined in tracker.component.ts. I'm really stuck, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Here's my tracker.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PTODataService } from './pto-data.service';
import { PTOData } from './pto-data';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-tracker',
    templateUrl: `./tracker.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./tracker.component.css']
})

export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit{
    empInfo: EmpInfo[] = new Array<EmpInfo>();
    ptoData: PTOData[];
    isHidden: boolean = false;
    
    selectedEmployee: EmpInfo;

    public selectedType: string = "PTO";

    constructor(
        private empInfoService: EmpInfoService,
        private ptoDataService: PTODataService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => this.empInfo = empInfo
            );
    }

    getPTOData(): void {
        this.ptoDataService.getPTODatas().then(
            ptoData => this.ptoData = ptoData
        );
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
        this.getPTOData();
    }

    toggleSummary(): void {
        this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
    }
}
```

my tracker.component.html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div [ngClass]="{'col-xs-12':isHidden === true, 'col-xs-7': isHidden !== false}">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="width:50px; height: 50px; float:right; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px;margin:5px;" (click)="toggleSummary()"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 no-pad" style="padding-bottom:50px;">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" id="empName" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee">
          <option selected="selected" disabled>Employee Name...</option>
          <option *ngFor="let emp of empInfo | orderByLast : 'LastName'" [ngValue]="emp">{{emp.EmpID}} - {{emp.FirstName}} {{emp.LastName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="PTOtype" [(ngModel)]="selectedType">
          <option selected="selected" value="PTO">PTO</option>
          <option value="etoEarned">ETO - Earned</option>
          <option value="etoUsed">ETO - Used</option>
          <option value="STDLTD">STD/LTD</option>
          <option value="Uncharged">Uncharged</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Full/Half</th>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>Scheduled?</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>In P/R?</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
              <span class="requestText">Requests:</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let pto of ptoData">
            <ng-container *ngIf="pto.type === selectedType">
              <ng-container *ngIf="pto.EmpKey === selectedEmployee?.EmpKey">
                <td>{{pto.date | date: 'MM/dd/y'}}</td>
                <td>{{pto.fullhalf}}</td>
                <td>{{pto.hours}}</td>
                <td>{{pto.scheduled}}</td>
                <td>{{pto.notes}}</td>
                <td>{{pto.inPR}}</td>
              </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div *ngIf="isHidden" class="col-xs-5">
        <pto-summary [empInfo]="selectedEmployee"></pto-summary>
  </div>
</div>
```

my summary.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { EmpInfoService } from './emp-info.service';
import { TrackerComponent } from './tracker.component';
import { EmpInfo } from './emp-info'; 

@Component({
    selector: 'pto-summary',
    templateUrl: `./summary.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./summary.component.css']
})

export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit{

    empInfo: EmpInfo[];
    @Input() selectedEmployee: EmpInfo;

    timeVar = " hours";
    checkboxValue = false;

    constructor(private empInfoService: EmpInfoService) { }

    getEmpInfo(): void {
        this.empInfoService.getEmpInfos().then(
            empInfo => this.empInfo = empInfo
        );
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getEmpInfo();
    }

    changeTime(): void {
        if (!this.checkboxValue)
        {
            this.timeVar = " hours"

            this.selectedEmployee.STDLTD = this.selectedEmployee.STDLTD * 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.Uncharged = this.selectedEmployee.Uncharged * 8;

            this.selectedEmployee.PTOBase = this.selectedEmployee.PTOBase * 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.PTOCarry = this.selectedEmployee.PTOCarry * 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.PTOBorrowed = this.selectedEmployee.PTOBorrowed * 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.PTOBalance = this.selectedEmployee.PTOBalance * 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.PTORequests = this.selectedEmployee.PTORequests * 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.PTORemaining = this.selectedEmployee.PTORemaining * 8;

            this.selectedEmployee.ETOEarned = this.selectedEmployee.ETOEarned * 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.ETORequests = this.selectedEmployee.ETORequests * 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.ETORemaining = this.selectedEmployee.ETORemaining * 8;
        }
        else
        {
            this.timeVar = " days"

            this.selectedEmployee.STDLTD = this.selectedEmployee.STDLTD / 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.Uncharged = this.selectedEmployee.Uncharged / 8;

            this.selectedEmployee.PTOBase = this.selectedEmployee.PTOBase / 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.PTOCarry = this.selectedEmployee.PTOCarry / 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.PTOBorrowed = this.selectedEmployee.PTOBorrowed / 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.PTOBalance = this.selectedEmployee.PTOBalance / 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.PTORequests = this.selectedEmployee.PTORequests / 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.PTORemaining = this.selectedEmployee.PTORemaining / 8;

            this.selectedEmployee.ETOEarned = this.selectedEmployee.ETOEarned / 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.ETORequests = this.selectedEmployee.ETORequests / 8;
            this.selectedEmployee.ETORemaining = this.selectedEmployee.ETORemaining / 8;
        }
    }
}
```

and my summary.component.html

```html
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">{{selectedEmployee.LastName | uppercase}} Summary</h3>
    <div style="float: right;">
      <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input [(ngModel)]="checkboxValue" (change)="changeTime()" type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
          <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
          <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="overflow-x:auto;">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Status </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <select class="form-control" id="empStatus" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.EmpStat" name="empStatus">
                <option value="Current">Current</option>
                <option value="Terminated">Terminated</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Anniversary </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empAnniversary" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.Anniversary" name="empAnniversary" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">years</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Start Date </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empStartDate" [ngModel]="selectedEmployee.StartDate | date: 'MM/dd/y'" name="empStartDate"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Adjusted Start </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empAdjustedStart" [ngModel]="selectedEmployee.AdjustedStart | date: 'MM/dd/y'" name="empAdjustedStart"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> STD/LTD </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empSTDLTD" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.STDLTD" name="empSTDLTD" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-5"> Uncharged </label>
            <div class="col-xs-7">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="empUncharged" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.Uncharged" name="empUncharged" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>


      <fieldset>

        <h4>PTO</h4>
        <br />

        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <label class="col-xs-2"> Base </label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBase" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.PTOBase" name="ptoBase" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#43; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Carryover </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoCarry" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.PTOCarry" name="ptoCarry" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Balance </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBalance" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.PTOBalance" name="ptoBalance" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#8213; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Borrowed </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBorrowed" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.PTOBorrowed" name="ptoBorrowed" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-1" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#8213; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Requests </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoRequests" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.PTORequests" name="ptoRequests" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
          <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-2" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#61; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Balance </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoBalance" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.PTOBalance" name="ptoBalance" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-1" style="font-weight: bold;"> &#61; </label>
            <label class="col-xs-4"> Available </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoRemaining" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.PTORemaining" name="ptoRemaining" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>


      <fieldset>

        <h4>ETO</h4>
        <br />

          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Earned </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoEarned" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.ETOEarned" name="etoEarned" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-xs-2"> &#8213; </label>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Requests </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoRequests" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.ETORequests" name="etoRequests" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr style="border: solid 1px black;border-bottom:1px solid black;clear:both" />
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-xs-2"> &#61; </label>
              <label class="col-xs-4"> Available </label>
              <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input class='form-control' type="text" id="etoRemaining" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee.ETORemaining" name="etoRemaining" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">{{timeVar}}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6"></div>

      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At line 7 of `tracker.component.html` you need to use two-way data binding to keep the value in sync with the model like so:

```js
[(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee"
```

Because the value is not set initially you need to use the elvis operator to access properties on the object. This will short-circuit if any part on the object chain is undefined. Like so:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="pto.EmpKey === selectedEmployee?.EmpKey">
```

To pass the selected employee to the summary component you need to setup an input parameter like so:

```js
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() selectedEmployee: EmpInfo;
}
```

And then provide that to the component in the tracker-component.html like so:

```html
<pto-summary [selectedEmployee]="selectedEmployee"></pto-summary>
```

Comment: that eliminates the error, but the table still doesn't print out when the name is selected

Comment: Does `getEmpInfo` return the data correctly and set it equal to empInfo. Is there data where `pto.EmpKey === selectedEmployee?.EmpKey`?

Comment: getEmpInfo does return the data correctly and set it equal to empInfo and I'm not sure, I'm leaning towards there not being for some reason because I just put a quick check statement of <h2>{{selectedEmployee?.EmpKey}}</h2> and nothing printed out

Comment: Okay so then it sounds like `selectedEmployee` value is not being set correctly as you stated. Initially it has no value; try printing the object to the page as you did before and then verify that it gets set when you choose an option from the dropdown.

Comment: It is okay for it to be null initially depending on your use case. Did you update the data-binding of the `select` as indicated in my answer to use two-way data-binding? `<select class="form-control" id="empName" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee">`

Comment: I had to do a hard refresh on my browser and then it worked, thanks! Now, how would I bring that over to my summary component? I'm getting the same error where it's saying "Cannot read property 'EmpStat' of undefined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146005/discussion-between-rcarc-and-teddy-sterne).

Comment: Update the html component binding to be: `<pto-summary [selectedEmployee]="selectedEmployee"></pto-summary>`